# Как с помощью сss сделать такое закругление блока?

Tags: html, css

Уже несколько дней не могу справиться с данной задачей. Мне нужно сделать такой закругленный блок. Пробовал задавать `border-radius: 50%` и менять разную высоту блока, но все равно как-то коряво получается. Подскажите, как такое вообще делается?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нет никакого экрана. Есть только окно. Границы окна.

Comment: Что есть здесь закругление?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как насчет такого варианта?

```css
.container {
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.section {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.section_light {
  background: #FBF3E6;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50% / 0 0 40px 40px;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.section_light .container {
  background: #fff;
}

.section_dark {
  background: #E5D0B3;
}

.section_dark .container {
  background: #EBD2AA;
}
```

```html
<div class="section section_light">
  <div class="container"></div>
</div>
<div class="section section_dark">
  <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

[Посмотреть код на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/a4Lcdw24/).